# How to count the number of lines and print the line number on each line in front of the result?

Tags: c#, regex, richtextbox

I'm trying to regex my way into a text file in order to search, count and display the results in a second richtextbox as we find what we are looking for throughout the text file (already loaded into the first richtextbox)

```
int totalOUTgroups = Lines(ofd.FileName)
  .Select(line => Regex.Matches(line, @"access-group\s+\w+\s+out\s+interface\s+\w+").Count)
  .Sum();

// then list the count into the box or save it for later reports   
if (totalOUTgroups > 0)
{
    richTextBox2.SelectionFont = new Font("Courier New", 8);
    richTextBox2.AppendText(">>>ACls using OUT are out: " + "\u2028");
    richTextBox2.AppendText(">>>Total found: " + totalOUTgroups.ToString() + "\u2028");
    string config = File.ReadAllText(ofd.FileName);
    string accessgroupOut = @"(access-group\s+\w+\s+out\s+interface\s+\w+)";

    Regex ace = new Regex(accessgroupOut, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
    Match findGroup = ace.Match(config);

    // Let's count each line we found a match and print that on our richtextbox2.
    int counter = 1;
    string line;
    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(ofd.FileName);

    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Contains(findGroup.Value))
        {
             foreach (Match findgroup in ace.Matches(config))
             {                                      
                 richTextBox2.AppendText("Line:" + " " + counter.ToString() + " "+ "" + findgroup.Value + "\u2028");
             }  
        }

    counter++;
    }
}
```

Ok, What I would like to have should be an output as:

```
>>>ACLs using OUT are out:
>>>Total Found: 3
Line: 15 access-group myaclname OUT interface outside.12
Line: 16 access-group youraclname OUT interface outside.1
Line: 17 access-group aclname OUT interface outside
```

Right now what I have is:

```
>>>ACLs using OUT are out:
>>>Total Found: 3
Line: 15 access-group myaclname OUT interface outside.12
Line: 15 access-group youraclname OUT interface outside.1
Line: 15 access-group aclname OUT interface outside
```

I'm a network engineer and C# is not my area of expertise, although I find it fascinating and learn more about it every day, specially here.

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint inside the while-loop to check the value of counter as you are reading lines from the file? (Also, There was an issues with mismatched braces when I just edited the code snippet in your question. If `counter++` is not inside the while-loop it won't work as expected...)

Comment: seems like you're using "config" when you should be using "line" in ace.Matches

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method would be to read each line and have a counter keep track.

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("test.txt")) 
{
    int counter = 1;
    string line = r.ReadLine();
    while (line != null) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine (counter.ToString() + ": " + line);
        counter++;
        line = r.ReadLine ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Damon, 

It counts only one group. 

if you put below of another group it simply stops counting and returns null